# Typescript Create a type whose properties are the properties of an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have an interface definition as follows

```
export interface RoutingMap {
    ticket: {
        id: number
    },
    car: {
        model: string,
        make: number
    }
}
```

I want to be able to create an interface for an object, which has 2 properties - 1 being a key in the `RoutingMap` and the other being whatever the type of that `Key` in the `RoutingMap` is.

In pseudo-code I image it looking like this

```
export interface RoutingMessage {
    resource: keyof RoutingMap,
    params: RoutingMap["resource"]
}
```

The end goal is for me to be able to construct objects like this

```
const msg: RoutingMessage = {
    resource: "ticket",
    params: { id: 10 }
}

const invalidMsg: RoutingMessage = {
    resource: "something", //TS error - "something" is not a key of routing map
    params: { id: 10 }
}

const invalidMsg2: RoutingMessage = {
    resource: "car"
    params: { model: "tesla", make: true } //TS error - "make" is not a boolean
}

const invalidMsg3: RoutingMessage = {
    resource: "car"
    params: { id: 123 } //TS error - id is not assinable to  {model: string, make: boolean}
}
```

The `RoutingMap` is something which would be extended with time, and people should be able to create specific objects, based on the keys (and their values)

As you can see from the pseudo-code example I can set a constraint for the resource, but I need a way to constrain the params property to only allow objects, which match the signature of the `Key` in the `RoutingMap`

Comment: You want `RoutingMessage` to be a union type (not an interface) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NlgeRw).  If that works for your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise what am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to accept or reject `const okayOrNot: RoutingMessage = { resource: "car", params: { id: 123 } }` where the `resource` and `params` do not match up?  Either way you might want to [edit] your question to specify the behavior you expect for that so that answers can make sure to address it

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer. The union type works perfectly. I should have pointed out I don't necessarily need an interface. You can add an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.
Also updated the question to include the behavior in your second comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are a finite number of keys that match `keyof RoutingMap`, you can write `RoutingMessage` as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types where each element of the union corresponds to a particular key, like this:

```
type RoutingMessage = {
    resource: "ticket";
    params: {
        id: number;
    };
} | {
    resource: "car";
    params: {
        model: string;
        make: number;
    };
}
```

You can compute `RoutingMessage` programmatically from `RoutingMap` by writing it as a "distributive object type" (terminology borrowed from [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where we make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property with key `K` in `RoutingMap` is mapped to the desired object type for that key, and then we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with `keyof RoutingMap`, producing the desired union.

```
type RoutingMessage = { [K in keyof RoutingMap]:
  { resource: K, params: RoutingMap[K] }
}[keyof RoutingMap];
```

With the above definition, `RoutingMessage` will gain new union members whenever a new property is added to `RoutingMap`, as desired.

---

Let's make sure it behaves how you want:

```
const msg: RoutingMessage = {
  resource: "ticket",
  params: { id: 10 }
}; // okay

const invalidMsg: RoutingMessage = {
  resource: "something", // error!
  //~~~~~~ <-- Type '"something"' is not assignable to type '"ticket" | "car"'
  params: { id: 10 }
};

const invalidMsg2: RoutingMessage = {
  resource: "car",
  params: { model: "tesla", make: true } // error!
  //  --------------------> ~~~~
  // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
};

const invalidMsg3: RoutingMessage = {
  resource: "car",
  params: { id: 123 } // error!
  // -----> ~~~~~~~
  // Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ model: string; make: number; }' 
};
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCuZQHMCycADsgN4BQyyOCA1hGAFxmVXLAAmzImAtgEbRWAXwA0rBHCjMKbZL3QcIAG2YBnMFDzi5vOPW59BUEeWHlyYAJ5EUGbHnwQ1auLhQBeMsgDaAaXYQZHordBg0LBwQAmIAXUZWUmQoZywoJGY-UWQiKTheNWZ7KJiif1jkc2EfELCIh2jCIliAbgsAegAqahs7SMdnV3dkL1k2FLU0jOQAIhp6MBm2uVyofMKWOTlOQwFoZbZhNuFkAB9N8dTMdIhmGckoJdYqVfWZZ62FJVVkDS1og5beT6W7IHh7KCAyrHZCddoWcgIdAgDTyNS4Ir9RqDNyeC4TKagubAOgMGY6HJ5AoydhcZAARgADJUzC1kO12sh0LQ4FYLEiUWBAgA3ODKTj4dGYhoEHHDUasAnXaYzSa8BgACzw5PZnOgUHQUAAhKwOQA-C2W5AAHgAtLbkAAVXrIADkqvQ6rAWuiM1d7DUYPQQrgLmAuBAcH4yhQYHQPVsbuJpMWZ1mDz9rFe1O8OwZzKqbURyNRoFF4o4ktwACZpSUnC5cSN8VcbncMxTsxskl8VHdIGplHAdXoDNQoJgUCcOch9YaTVQZ8h7SvV2v1wA+ZCWs2mznOxOu-jodAxuAgf3AQMgYPIUNqcOR6Ox+PWQ-g4yugB0rP5JaFZZihK6IAMx1gMjbyi2kzKkSHZZlS3a0sw9LViBlS6rOUAGsae7LquW47paeEHigrpJHmH77JUl7Xre96PlGMbUK+LrkfIih9r8mh4Gyo6glRkI0cgrJAA)

Answer (score 2):

```js
export interface RoutingMessage {
    resource: keyof RoutingMap,
    params: RoutingMap[this["resource"]]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way you think it does (at least not without more info).  It accepts  `const o: RoutingMessage = { resource: "car", params: { id: 123 } }` which is presumably not acceptable

Comment: @martin-wedvich works great, but as @jcalz pointed out - I want to constrain the `params` to only signatures, based on the type of the key in the `RouteMap`

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I guess unions are the only way to do this currently 